# ImportError: No module named 'backports'

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04

While installing retraining model using tensorflow, i ran the following command :

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain --image_dir <..directory..>
```

The error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'backports'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nishith/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 91, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/nishith/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/nishith/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *
  File "/home/nishith/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 100, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.subscribe import subscribe
  File "/home/nishith/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/subscribe.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import variables
  File "/home/nishith/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
  File "/home/nishith/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 70, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops
  File "/home/nishith/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util import tf_should_use
  File "/home/nishith/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py", line 28, in <module>
    from backports import weakref  # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
ImportError: No module named 'backports'
```

Comment: I did `pip install backports.weakref`， but the error was still there, and I finally found that it is the false setting of corresponding path to `PYTHONPATH` that matters.

Comment: @Jecky how did you diagnose and fix this?

Answer (score 18):

Try:

```
pip install backports.weakref
```